On the history of cone-3-manifolds
A cone-3-manifold (of constant curvature) is a geometric 3-manifold locally modelled either on the Euclidean/hyperbolic/spherical 3-space or on the respective metric cones over spherical cone-surfaces homeomorphic to the 2-spheres. Thurston is sometimes credited for them, after he used them in the proof of his hyperbolic Dehn filling theorem and in his approach to the orbifold theorem.
However, the idea of gluing a bunch of tetrahedra, endowing each with a Euclidean/hyperbolic/spherical metric, and studying the resulting object with its induced path metric seems natural and simple. I am wondering if there are any notable examples of studying/using them before Thurston.
I actually know one, but it is slightly stand-alone for me. Volkov, a student of Alexandrov, used them in 1950s to give a variational proof of the Alexandrov theorem: that every Euclidean cone-metric on the 2-sphere with cone-angles less than $2\pi$ admits a unique realization as the boundary of a Euclidean 3-polyhedron. Later Volkov managed to use them in a proof of the quantitative rigidity: if for two compact convex bodies in the Euclidean 3-space there is an $\epsilon$-isometry between their boundaries (i.e. a homeomorphism that distorts the distances by at most $\epsilon$), then this map extends to an $f(\epsilon)$-isometry between the bodies themselves, where $f$ is an explicit function with $f(0)=0$. Is there anything else?

Although I haven’t looked at it, the earliest reference is surely Poincaré’s 1882 paper ‘Theorie des groupes fuchsiens’, published in Acta. Apparently this is where he first stated his famous polygon theorem.

Here is earlier, but related, work on building manifolds out of geometric polyhedra:
In his thesis [1912] Gieseking builds a manifold $M$ by identifying the faces of a single regular ideal tetrahedron (see page 160).  He gives a presentation of the fundamental group, notes that the boundary is a Klein bottle, and discusses the subgroup of $\pi_1(M)$ (of index two) consisting of orientation-preserving loops.  Later in the thesis (page 227) he gives an overview of Wirtinger presentation of knot groups.  However, it seems that he does not know that the double cover of $M$ is homeomorphic to the figure-eight knot complement.
Seifert and Weber [1933] give the first example of a closed hyperbolic manifold $N$, build out of a single regular dodecahedron with dihedral angle $2\pi/5$.  They discuss tessellations of the three-sphere, euclidean space, and hyperbolic space by platonic solids (page 241).  It seems that they know how to obtain many spherical and euclidean space forms as quotients of such tessellations (page 240).  They end by showing that $N$ is a five-fold branched cover over the Whitehead link (introduced by Whitehead in 1935).

Poincaré published his polyhedron theorem in 1883 (following his polygon theorem in 1882). Surely this is the origin of the idea of constructing geometric structures on 3-manifolds by gluing sides of polyhedra?

Poincaré (1883) points to work of Schottky and Klein as predating his… I suppose that all of those examples have infinite volume.  There is work after Poincaré, but before Gieseking (perhaps by Bianchi?), producing fundamental domains for the actions of the symmetry groups of various forms… I think that these examples have torsion?  I suppose, at the end of the day, the examples I listed are the ones I know best  and not the “first” ones (if the idea of “first” means anything!).
